# Lock table cell width, without specifying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I'm trying to dynamically create a table from js, although I do know the exact width and height of the table, I do not know the actual width of table cell. I know that it is possible to find the width of the each cell, but I was wondering if you can actually lock it without specifying the width of the cell.

Link to jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j3TEz/21/

My js file:

```
window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
function init(){
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
var tr = 3;
var td=5;

var innerTable = '';

for(var trCounter=0;trCounter<tr;trCounter++){
    innerTable+='<tr>';

    for(var tdCounter=0;tdCounter<td;tdCounter++){
       var id=(trCounter*td)+tdCounter;
       innerTable+='<td id="'+id+'" onclick="addText('+id+')"></td>';                         
    }

    innerTable+='</tr>';
}

table.style.width="600px";
table.style.height="300px";
table.style.border="1px solid black";
table.innerHTML=innerTable;
}



function addText(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="Lorem Ipsum";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, if you don't give a width wich width the cell must assume and keep fixed on it?

Comment: When the table is created every cell has the same width and height, but whenever I add some content to a specific <td> that changes, so I am basically trying to fix the width of every cell after the table is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css table-layout set to fixed will keep the columns width fixed, the size will be determined by  the first row columns.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the width. However, it doesn't fix the height. Is there any way to also fix the height.

Comment: For the table or the rows?

Comment: The height don't work properly in IE, my formula is: forget the <tr> height, set the height and max-height per <td>, don't put text inside the <td> directly, insert a <p> inside the <td> for your text and set the height, max-height and overflow:hidden for it. You can make it easy setting the css for <td> and <p> that belong your table.